# How to add BSSID in listView when scanning for WiFi?

Tags: java, android

I have this code and it works fine, but I only get my a wifi network name, not the BSSID too. I need network name in Item and BSSID in subItem of ListView. Here's my code:

```
public class Wifi_list extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
 {      
    WifiManager wifi;       
    ListView lv;
    int size = 0;
    List<ScanResult> results;
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;
    private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();
    private int progressBarStatus = 0;
    private long fileSize = 0;
    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver;

    String ITEM_KEY = "key";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    /* Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   //full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.wifi_list);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Wifi_list.this, arraylist, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { ITEM_KEY }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

        arraylist.clear();          
        wifi.startScan();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        lv.setAdapter(this.adapter);
        lv.setClickable(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                //scanWifi();
            }
        });

        myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) 
            {
               results = wifi.getScanResults();
               size = results.size();
               for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--){
                   HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();                       
                   item.put(ITEM_KEY, results.get(i).SSID);
                   arraylist.add(item);
               }
               if(size>0)
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this portion

```
for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--){
    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();                       
    item.put(ITEM_KEY, results.get(i).SSID);
    arraylist.add(item);
}
```

you only have one entry in your item map, the value of `results.get(i).SSID`.  A [`ScanResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html) also has `public String BSSID` (The address of the access point).  Add that to your map inside the loop.

```
for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--){
    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();                       
    item.put(ITEM_KEY, results.get(i).SSID);
    item.put("BSSID", results.get(i).BSSID);
    arraylist.add(item);
}
```

You may also want to change `ITEM_KEY` to reflect the actual name of the key/value pair ("SSID").  Right now it is just simply, "`key`"

Comment: what doesn't work? do you get the SSID value but not the BSSID value after implementing that change? Does the code ever enter into that for loop?

Comment: Yes I get SSID value but nothing below that in the ListView. So, no BSSID.

Comment: Oh, you need to additionally add the reference to "BSSID" when  you instantiate your `SimpleAdapter` in the `from` parameter. `new String[] { ITEM_KEY, "BSSID" }`